# Tcl - search and delete

Tags: tcl

The variable `foo` is set as so:

```
set foo "-sc 0x8 -di U -fwl /remote/sweden/users/california/script/bu/c/fw/rel -phy /remote/sweden/users/california/script/bu/c/init -bui /remote/sweden/users/california/script/bu -se 1 "
```

I want to delete the following text from `foo`:

```
-fwl /remote/sweden/users/california/script/bu/c/fw/rel -phy /remote/sweden/users/california/script/bu/c/init -bui /remote/sweden/users/california/script/bu
```

Whatever comes after (and including) `-fwl`, `-phy`, and `-bui` should be deleted. The order of appearance of `-fwl`, `-phy`, `-bui` in this string is not guaranteed.

In the end, `foo` should look like this:

```
-sc 0x8 -di U -se 1
```

How do I do this in Tcl?

Answer (score 2):

A list of key-value pairs is just a [tcl dictionary](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/dict.html#M28). So let's use [`dict unset`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/dict.html#M24) to remove the indicated entries, regardless of their order of appearance:

```
set foo "-sc 0x8 -di U -fwl /remote/sweden/users/california/script/bu/c/fw/rel -phy /remote/sweden/users/california/script/bu/c/init -bui /remote/sweden/users/california/script/bu -se 1 "
foreach key {-fwl -phy -bui} { dict unset foo $key }
puts $foo ;# -sc 0x8 -di U -se 1
```

Comment: Or just: `puts [dict remove $foo -fwl -phy -bui]`

Comment: @SchelteBron Depends on if you want to change the original variable or not. If not, prefer that way, yeah.

Comment: (It's kind of inconsistent and annoying that multiple keys with `dict unset` describes a path in a nested dict, but multiple independent keys with `dict remove`)

Comment: If you want to change the original value: `set foo [dict remove $foo -fwl -phy -bui]`. And if you worry about duplicating data: `set foo [dict remove $foo[set foo {}] -fwl -phy -bui]`. See the [Tcl wiki](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/K) for an explanation of how that works.

Comment: @Shawn It's a consistency vs usability trade-off, compounded by the fact that I regard supporting arbitrary keys (especially including spaces) as an essential design requirement of dictionaries. We don't want to force you to use `list` to build compound keys, so some ops are awkward to express.